# onclick event isn't calling my function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

So im trying to make a simple pizza ordering page, but from what i can tell there is nothing wrong with my code. However, when the user clicks on the place order button, the javascript function that I have created isnt called! I am not sure what I am doing wrong!!!

I have posted my code, here, any help is appreciated! thanks!

here is the function placeOrder(f)

```
function finalOrder(f)
        {
            var response;
            var osize;
            var otop = "";
            var ocrust;
                if (f.psize[0].checked == true)
                      osize = f.psize[0].value;
                  else if (f.psize[1].checked == true)
                           osize = f.psize[1].value;
                  else if (f.psize[2].checked == true)
                           osize = f.psize[2].value;
                  else if (f.psize[3].checked == true)
                           osize = f.psize[3].value;

                  if (f.crust[0].checked == true)
                      ocrust = f.crust[0].value;
                  else if (f.crust[1].checked == true)
                           ocrust = f.crust[1].value;
                  else if (f.crust[2].checked == true)
                           ocrust = f.crust[2].value;
                  else if (f.crust[3].checked == true)
                           ocrust = f.crust[3].value;

                  if (f.cb1.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb1.value;
                  if (f.cb2.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb2.value;
                  if (f.cb3.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb3.value;
                  if (f.cb4.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb4.value;
                  if (f.cb5.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb5.value;
                  if (f.cb6.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb6.value;
                  if (f.cb7.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb7.value;
                  if (f.cb8.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb8.value;
                  if (f.cb9.checked == true)
                      otop = otop + f.cb9.value;
                  if (f.cb1o.checked == true)
                    otop = otop + f.cb10.value;

                  response = confirm("Please confirm: a "+osize+" with "+otop+""+ocrust+" from the store in "+document.orderDetails.storeMenu.value+" for a price of "+document.orderDetails.displayTotal.value);
                   if (response==true)
                    {
                            alert("Thank you for your order!");
                       }
                    else
                        {
                            alert("Your order has been cancelled.");
                        }
        }
```

and here is where i call it using an onclick event

```
<p>
            Price Including Tax:
                <input  id="tax" type="text" name="displayTotal" size="10">
                <input  id="placeOrder" type="button" name="placeOrder" value="Place Order" onclick = "finalOrder(document.pizzaSize);">
        </p>
```

pizzaSize is another form which a user selects items for their pizza, and I have confirmed it is correct.

Any help is awesome, thanks!

update:
here is a link to fiddle that i made - http://jsfiddle.net/jcritch/L8A4a/

Comment: Have you checked the output of the Javascript console?

Comment: could you create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. I kinda new to html and javascript. A friend and i have been working on the same code, and his works, so I changed my code to model his, and for some reason mine does not work

Comment: I can try...never used this either :S I will break up my code to see if i can get it working on fiddle

Comment: alright, see if this works http://jsfiddle.net/jcritch/L8A4a/

Answer (score 0):

Holy if check batman, you should really try to simplify this.

```
function finalOrder(f) {
    var response,
        osize,
        otop = "",
        ocrust;

    for(var i = f.psize.length; i--;){
        if(f.psize[i].checked)
            osize = f.psize[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(var i = f.crust.length; i--;){
        if (f.crust[i].checked)
            ocrust = f.crust[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var checkbox = f.getElementsByName('cb'+(i+1))[0];

        if (checkbox.checked)
            otop += checkbox.value;
        }
    }

    var response = confirm("Please confirm: a "+osize+" with "+otop+""+ocrust+" from the store in "+document.orderDetails.storeMenu.value+" for a price of "+document.orderDetails.displayTotal.value);

    if (response) {
        alert("Thank you for your order!");
    } else {
        alert("Your order has been cancelled.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also noticed that you were checking if `reply` instead of `response`, which was your variable. Likely thats why you didn't see a message. I added the `return false` because I assume you don't want to process the form if canceled.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I went ahead and changed taht on mine. However, I just changed the name from reply to response. Previously, it was all reply, and it still wasn't working. heres a link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jcritch/L8A4a/

Comment: I agree, what a darn mess of if checks, this is an product ordering  and customer facing, I'd really advise a boat load of testing and then get a Super Tanker of testing tools and use them too and have someone else test it.  The margins for pizza  places that are independent are not that large to afford many mistakes in ordering.

Comment: yeah @user3424191 -> i tried working with your jsfiddle, and there is just too much broken that is going on for me to tackle without being paid for it haha. i would start fresh, break each step out into segments, test that segment, and then continue building. otherwise you're doomed to wonder if its step 14,238 of 23,840 thats causing the failure or if its step 18,220.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have never used fiddle so its probably jsut that. i am using text pad and just moved it over to fiddle. thanks though. I know that the problem has to do with calling of the finalOrder() function, as the other functions are being called fine.